# Parallel Fork-Manager: fragments of other child process in output

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

We have a perl application which receives an XML as input, does some work on certain elements (let's call them parent-elements) and gives back a stream of XML's of those changed elements.

For fast processing Parallel ForkManager is used.

As input parameters, maximum number of processes for P. ForkManager can be set as well as number of parent-elements processed per process.

---

Problem is that from time to time a parent-element of process X is broken after 1024 chars with content of parent-element of process Y:

**Normal case:**

Process x delivers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<abdocx xmlns="someurl/abdocx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="someurl/abdocx abxml.xsd">
<parent-element-X>
       <x1></x1>
       <x2></x2>
       <x3></x3>
       <x4></x4>
       <x5></x5>
</parent-element-X>
</aadocx>
```

Process y delivers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<abdocx xmlns="someurl/abdocx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="someurl/abdocx abxml.xsd">
<parent-element-Y>
       <y1></y1>
       <y2></y2>
       <y3></y3>
       <y4></y4>
       <y5></y5>
</parent-element-Y>
</aadocx>
```

**Broken case with two XML from two processes mixed up:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<abdocx xmlns="someurl/abdocx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="someurl/adocx abxml.xsd">
<parent-element-X>
       <x1></x1>
       <x2></x2>
       <x3></x3><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<abdocx xmlns="someurl/abdocx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="someurl/abdocx abxml.xsd">
<parent-element-Y>
       <y1></y1>
       <y2></y2>
       <y3></y3>
       <y4></y4>
       <y5></y5>
</parent-element-Y>
</aadocx>
       <x4></x4>
       <x5></x5>
</parent-element-X>
</aadocx>
```

---

- We tried around with different settings (number of processes in Parallel-ForkManager, different number of parent-elements processed per process) as well with different versions of Parallel-ForkManager Modul. Nothing changed behaviour.
- When doing the same job several times, number of broken cases changes as well as parent-elements involved.
- Besides this, problem does not show up if number of processes in Parallel-ForkManager ist set to 1.
- With help of Data::Dumper Modul we were able to see in broken case both XML really have their root in a separate process:

  if (1) {  # simple on/off switch to display the contents
  print &Dumper($data_structure_reference) . qq|end of "$ident" sent structure\n$
  }

Did we do something wrong in Parallel-ForkManager? Or might this be a bug inside the Parallel-ForkManager-Modul?

---

These are the relevant code fragments:

**Initialization of Parallel ForkManager**

```
require Parallel::ForkManager;
    $self->{_procmanager} = new Parallel::ForkManager($self->{_conf}->{'maxproc'}, '/tmp');   # /tmp is needed for inter-process-communication

    $self->{_retrieved_responses} = ();
    $self->{_subprocess_jobs} = ();

    # data structure retrieval and handling
    $self->{_procmanager}->run_on_finish (
        sub {
            my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $data_structure_reference) = @_;

            # see what the child sent us, if anything
            if (defined($data_structure_reference)) {  # test rather than assume child sent anything
                my $reftype = ref($data_structure_reference);

                # we can also collect retrieved data structures for processing after all children have exited
                $self->{_retrieved_responses}->{$ident} = $data_structure_reference;
                #foreach my $abid (keys %{$data_structure_reference}) {
                #   print STDERR "PROCESSED: $abid\t$data_structure_reference->{$abid}->{'state'}\n";
                #}
            } else {
                print STDERR sprintf("%06d", $ident)."-$pid havent recieved anything. died?\n";
            }
        }
    );
(....)
```

**Dispatching in end_element**

```
# -------------------------------
# end of tag
# reset remembered positions
# -------------------------------
sub end_element {
    my $self = shift;
    my $element = shift;
    
    #print "End element: $element->{Name}\n";

    # block is done push to stack
    if(($element->{Name} eq 'stdout') && defined $self->{_currentConfig}) {
        $self->{_currentConfig}->{'output'} = "stdout";
    }

    # End block
    # 1. push job onto todo list
    # 2. if there are more than 'jobsize' jobs. try to run (call referenced function in xxx.pl).
    if(($element->{Name} eq 'xxx_yyy') && defined $self->{_currentConfig}) {
        #if(!-r $self->{_currentConfig}->{input}) {
        #print STDERR "!!!!!! [$self->{_currentConfig}->{input}]\n";
        #}
        push(@{$self->{_todo}}, $self->{_currentConfig});
        $self->{_abids}->{$self->{_currentConfig}->{'abid'}} = $self->{_currentConfig};
        if(scalar @{$self->{_todo}} >= $self->{_conf}->{'jobsize'}) {
            $self->dispatch();
        }
    }

    $self->{_currentNode} = undef;
    if(defined $self->{_position}->{$element->{Name}}) {
        $self->{_position}->{$element->{Name}} = 0; 
        $self->{_position}->{"sub$element->{Name}"} = 0;
    } 
}
(....)
```

**Dispatching in end_document**

```
# -------------------------------
# end of document
# wait until all childs have finished
# -------------------------------
sub end_document {
    my $self = shift;

    # we are at the end of document
    # release documents which are unassigned and still in queue
    if(scalar @{$self->{_todo}} > 0) {  
        $self->dispatch();
    }

    # wait for all processes to finish
    $self->{_procmanager}->wait_all_children;

    #foreach my $abid (keys %{$self->{_abids}}) {
    #   print STDERR "unprocessed: $abids\n";
    #} 

    # remove all processed files from file list - unprocessed will stay in list
    # unprocessed means that the converted died before processing the file
    foreach my $proc (sort keys %{$self->{_retrieved_responses}}) {
        foreach my $l (keys %{$self->{_retrieved_responses}->{$proc}}) {
            if(defined $self->{_abids}->{$l}) {
                delete $self->{_abids}->{$l};
            }
        }
    }


    #foreach my $abid (keys %{$self->{_abids}}) {
    #   print STDERR "unprocessed: $abid\n";
    #} 

    # print unprocessed files
    foreach my $l (keys %{$self->{_abids}}) {
        #if(defined $self->{_abids}->{$l}->{'procid'}) {
        #    print STDERR "$l PROCESSED\n";
        #}
        my $out = $self->generateFailXML(\%{$self->{_abids}->{$l}}, "FAIL_UNPROCESSED", 0);
        # copy file to desired output location - original will stay in docdir
        if(length($out) > 0 && $self->{_conf}->{'output'} && $self->{_conf}->{'output'} eq "-") {
            print $out;
        }
    }

    print STDERR "all done...\n";
}
(....)
```

**Dispatch and part of Subprocess**

```
# -------------------------------
# we have enough data to dispatch a process
# -------------------------------
sub dispatch {
    my $self = shift;

    my @todo = splice(@{$self->{_todo}},0,$self->{_conf}->{'jobsize'}); 
    $self->{_procid}++;

    my $pid = $self->{_procmanager}->start($self->{_procid}) and return;
    my %response = ();
    # child process
    $self->subprocess($self->{_procid}, \@todo, \%response, $self->{_conf}->{'process_group'});#, $self->{_semaphore});
    $self->{_procmanager}->finish(0, \%response);
}


# -----------------------------------------
# Process - Run this as an own process
# -----------------------------------------
sub subprocess {
    my $self = shift;
    my $id = shift;     # process id generated by forkmanager
    my $tasklist = shift;   # tasks to process (array)
    my $rhref = shift;      # Reference to hash which is returned to parent process
    my $pgroup = shift;
    #my $sem = shift;
    my $tid = sprintf("%06d", $id); # a more fancy processid;

    my $pid = $$;
    my $origcmd = $0;
    $0 = $0 . " [[$tid-$pid]]";
    setpgrp(0,$pgroup);
    print STDERR "Setting ProcessGroupd: $pgroup\n";
    (....)
```

**Output result**

```
# Output handling needs a big rewrite
# copy file to desired output location - original will stay in docdir
if((defined $self->{_conf}->{'batch'}) && (defined ${$cItem}{'output'})) {
    # Blocking code
    {
        # Lock the semaphore
        $self->{_semaphore}->op( 0, -1, SEM_UNDO );
        {
            print STDERR "DEBUG2!!!!!\n";
            if(lc(${$cItem}{'output'}) eq 'stdout') {
                if(defined $outfile) {
                    system("cat $outfile");
                } else {
                    my $out = $self->generateFailXML(\%{$self->{_abids}->{$abid}}, $cstate[0], $cstate[1], $cstate[2], $cstate[3], $cstate[4]);
                    if(length($out) > 0) {
                    print STDOUT $out;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(defined $outfile) {
                    system("cat $outfile >> ${$cItem}{'output'}");
                } else {
                    my $out = $self->generateFailXML(\%{$self->{_abids}->{$abid}}, $cstate[0], $cstate[1], $cstate[2], $cstate[3], $cstate[4]);
                    if(length($out) > 0) {
                    if(open(FH, ">>${$cItem}{'output'}")) {
                        print FH $out;
                        close(FH);
                    } else {
                        print STDERR $out;
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
        }

        # Unlock the semaphore
        $self->{_semaphore}->op( 0, 1, SEM_UNDO );
    }
    # End blocking code
unlink($outfile) if (defined $outfile);
}
```

**Used Perl-Modules**

Test-Simple-1.001003 
Test-Tester-0.109 
Test-NoWarnings-1.04 
Test-Deep-0.112 
Test-Inter-1.05 
Test-Pod-1.48 
Data-Dumper-2.173 
Time-Local-1.30 
Devel-Symdump-2.17 
Pod-Parser-1.63 
Pod-Coverage-0.23 
Test-Pod-Coverage-1.08 
OLE-Storage_Lite-0.20 
IO-String-1.08 
IO-stringy-2.110 
IPC-Run-0.92 
Module-Build-0.4218 
File-BaseDir-0.07 
File-Path-Expand-1.02 
MailTools-2.13 
MIME-tools-5.505 
MIME-Types-2.04 
File-MimeInfo-0.26 
YAML-Syck-1.27 
Date-Manip-6.46 
Carp-Clan-6.04 
Bit-Vector-7.3 
Date-Calc-6.3-weblaw 
TimeDate-2.31 
Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.068 
Compress-Raw-Bzip2-2.068 
IO-Compress-2.068 
Archive-Zip-1.30 
HTML-Tagset-3.20 
HTML-Parser-3.71 
Text-Iconv-1.7 
Proc-ProcessTable-0.50 
Encode-2.84 
Parallel-ForkManager-2.02 
Crypt-RC4-2.02 
Digest-Perl-MD5-1.9 
File-Path-2.09 
Capture-Tiny-0.25 
Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65 
Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.12  
Module-Pluggable-5.2 
Email-Date-Format-1.004 
Email-Simple-2.201 
Email-FolderType-0.813 
Email-Address-1.905 
Email-MessageID-1.402 
Email-MIME-ContentType-1.017 
Email-MIME-Encodings-1.315 
Email-MIME-1.926 
Email-LocalDelivery-1.200 
Email-Outlook-Message-0.914 
libxml-perl-0.08 
HTML-StripScripts-1.06 
HTML-StripScripts-Parser-1.03 
Sort-Versions-1.5 
Font-TTF-1.04 
Class-ISA-0.36 
Switch-2.17 
Log-Log4perl-1.44

Perl Version:

- This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Ubuntu Version:

- Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-184-generic x86_64)

Comment: What ado you mean by "delivers" (so I know where to look in this lengthy code)? Are you refering to `print $out`?

Comment: "Process x delivers" means what is given back from process x to the final stream of resulting XML's (as output after executing main perl script). Hope this helps?

Comment: No. What means are you using to deliver it? Or what in the code does the delivering? Is it the `print $out`?

Comment: I added some code under "Output result". This should be the relevant part. I have to say that I'm pretty new to perl and code exists for some years and was not written by me :). But I'm the one who should fix it...

Comment: I see 7 different forms of output in the section you just mentioned, 4 of which involve streams of text. Which one are are you asking about! At this point, I will insist on a runnable demonstration (as required) before I look any further

Comment: It's the first case, just "system("cat $outfile")"